# Integration testing in React

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, integration-testing, react-testing-library, vitest

You can view my app in my [repository](https://github.com/W01v3n/TodoApp/tree/tests/vitest), make sure you're on the `tests/vitest` branch.

---

### The Problem

I am trying to incorporate integration tests for my components. The thing is, in my app I always check if a user is authenticated. This happens in a component called `AuthContext.tsx` and it uses `/auth/re` and `/auth/refresh-token` to verify if a user is authenticated (if he has a valid token cookie).

Now, I understood that in `react-testing-library` there is no way to use cookies, and there is no need to. I am very confused. Should I simulate exactly how my app works? Or just manipulate my components (i.e TodoListsPage) to render correctly by mocking a 200 response without correctly implementing the authentication logic (cookies) in the tests?

I can't even control the routes `/auth/re` and `/auth/refresh-token` from my test file because these requests happen in the background, not from the actual components, they happen because of `AuthContext.tsx` running in useEffect and with the interceptor in `api.service.ts`

---

### What I tried

So even if I wanted to send some false data in the body like `isAuthenticated: true` I couldn't, these requests happen in the background for every component in the app. Just in case someone asks why, it's to show different things based on the users' authentication status, i.e if he is authenticated, the navigation bar won't show Login or Register, it'll add the Logout button, and more stuff like allowing access to a protected component.

If you look in my repository's `mocks.ts` under `frontend/src/tests/mocks.ts` you'll see that in `/auth/re` and `/auth/refresh-token` I return 200, in that situation, all tests pass. But I don't think this is testing the app correctly, because, what happens if the user comes with no cookies? Or without a valid token? Obviously I tried to just return 401 and see what happens, what happens is that the tests fail, because the test files cannot handle that 401, when that happens, the tests fail and error out like this:

```
⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯ Unhandled Errors ⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯

Vitest caught 17 unhandled errors during the test run.
This might cause false positive tests. Resolve unhandled errors to make sure your tests are not affected.

⎯⎯⎯⎯ Unhandled Rejection ⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401
 ❯ settle ../../../../../Web%20Development/Practice/Projects/ToDoApp/frontend/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:19:12
 ❯ XMLHttpRequestOverride.onloadend ../../../../../Web%20Development/Practice/Projects/ToDoApp/frontend/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:107:7
 ❯ XMLHttpRequestOverride.trigger node_modules/@mswjs/interceptors/src/interceptors/XMLHttpRequest/XMLHttpRequestOverride.ts:174:17
 ❯ node_modules/@mswjs/interceptors/src/interceptors/XMLHttpRequest/XMLHttpRequestOverride.ts:352:16

⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
Serialized Error: Object {
  "code": "ERR_BAD_REQUEST",
  "config": Object {
    "adapter": [Array],
    "baseURL": "http://localhost:3000/api",
    "data": undefined,
    "env": [Object],
    "headers": [Object],
    "maxBodyLength": -1,
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "method": "post",
    "timeout": 0,
    "transformRequest": [Array],
    "transformResponse": [Array],
    "transitional": [Object],
    "url": "/auth/refresh-token",
    "validateStatus": "Function<validateStatus>",
    "withCredentials": true,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
...
```

---

### Related Code

`frontend/src/tests/mocks.ts`

```
import { rest } from "msw";
import { setupServer } from "msw/node";

const loggedInUser = {
  userId: 1,
  username: "TestUser",
  email: "test@example.com",
  createdAt: new Date(),
  updatedAt: new Date(),
};

const registeringUser = {
  userId: 1,
  username: "Mr.Tester",
  email: "testregister@example.com",
  password_hash:
    "$argon2id$v=19$m=65536,t=3,p=4$IOoj5cb1oogts/0YR/1HAQ$8Xj/AEsLO09h02mdwd6ffULZiUYBW802cJtX4QwWoss",
  createdAt: new Date(),
  updatedAt: new Date(),
};

const todoLists = [
  {
    createdAt: new Date(),
    id: 1,
    name: "Tests List",
    updatedAt: new Date(),
    userId: 1,
  },
  {
    createdAt: new Date(),
    id: 2,
    name: "Tests List2",
    updatedAt: new Date(),
    userId: 1,
  },
];

const restHandlers = [
  rest.post("http://localhost:3000/api/users/login", async (_req, res, ctx) => {
    const { email, password } = await _req.json();
    if (email === "test@example.com" && password === "password123") {
      return res(ctx.status(200), ctx.json(loggedInUser));
    } else {
      return res(
        ctx.status(401),
        ctx.json({ message: "Error in authentication." })
      );
    }
  }),

  rest.post(
    "http://localhost:3000/api/users/register",
    async (_req, res, ctx) => {
      const { username, email, password } = await _req.json();
      if (
        email === "testregister@example.com" &&
        password === "password123" &&
        username === "Mr.Tester"
      ) {
        return res(ctx.status(201), ctx.json(registeringUser));
      } else {
        console.log("ERROR IN REGISTRATION!");

        return res(
          ctx.status(401),
          ctx.json({ message: "Error in registration." })
        );
      }
    }
  ),

  rest.get("http://localhost:3000/api/auth/re", (_req, res, ctx) => {
    return res(ctx.status(200), ctx.json({ isAuthenticated: false }));
  }),

  rest.post(
    "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/refresh-token",
    (_req, res, ctx) => {
      return res(
        ctx.status(200),
        ctx.json({
          message: "Refresh token not found. (Relax, it's just a mock..)",
        })
      );
    }
  ),

  rest.get("http://localhost:3000/api/lists", (_req, res, ctx) => {
    return res(ctx.status(200), ctx.json(todoLists));
  }),
];

export const server = setupServer(...restHandlers);
```

`frontend/src/tests/setup.ts`

```
import { expect, beforeEach, afterEach, beforeAll, afterAll, vi } from "vitest";
import { cleanup } from "@testing-library/react";
import matchers from "@testing-library/jest-dom/matchers";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import { server } from "./mocks";

expect.extend(matchers);

beforeAll(() => server.listen({ onUnhandledRequest: "error" }));

beforeEach(() => {
  vi.resetAllMocks();
});

afterEach(() => {
  cleanup();
  server.resetHandlers();
  vi.clearAllMocks();
});

afterAll(() => server.close());
```

`frontend/src/Context/AuthContext.tsx`

```
// Import necessary packages and components.
import { createContext, useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";
import { RouteProps } from "react-router-dom";
import api from "../../services/api.service";

// Define the structure of a User object.
interface User {
  rest?: User;
  id: number;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  createdAt: Date;
  updatedAt: Date;
}

// Define the structure of the authentication context.
// This context will hold the current user, a loading state, and methods to log in and log out.
interface AuthContextData {
  currentUser: User | null;
  setCurrentUser: (user: User | null) => void;
  setIsAuthenticated: (isAuthenticated: boolean) => void;
  isLoading: boolean;
  // login: (email: string, password: string) => Promise<void>;
  logout: () => void;
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  refreshToken: () => Promise<void>;
}

// Create the context with React's createContext function.
// This context can hold a value of type AuthContextData, or it can be undefined.
// Initially, it's set to undefined.
const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextData | undefined>(undefined);

// Create a provider component. This component will provide the authentication context to all of its children.
// This is a common pattern in React: we define a context, then provide it using a special component.
export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: RouteProps) => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState<boolean>(false);

  // The current user and loading state are held in state variables.
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

  // Use the useCookies hook to get access to the cookies
  const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies(["token"]);

  // When the component mounts, it makes a request to the /auth/re endpoint to see if there is an authenticated user.
  useEffect(() => {
    const checkAuthenticatedUser = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await api.get("/auth/re");
        if (response.data.isAuthenticated) {
          setCurrentUser(response.data.rest);
          setIsAuthenticated(true);
        } else {
          setIsAuthenticated(false);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        const refreshTokenResponse = await api.post("/auth/refresh-token");
        if (refreshTokenResponse.data.token) {
          // Retry to see if the user is now authenticated
          const response = await api.get("/auth/re");
          if (response.data.isAuthenticated) {
            setCurrentUser(response.data.rest);
            setIsAuthenticated(true);
          }
        }
        console.log(error);
        setCurrentUser(null);
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };

    checkAuthenticatedUser();
  }, [cookies, isAuthenticated, isLoading]);

  async function refreshToken() {
    try {
      const response = await api.post("/auth/refresh-token");

      if (response.data.token) {
        setCurrentUser(response.data.rest);
        setCookie("token", response.data.token, { path: "/" });
        setIsAuthenticated(true);
      } else {
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // console.log(error);
      setCurrentUser(null);
      setIsAuthenticated(false);
      removeCookie("token");
    }
  }

  // The logout function makes a POST request to the /auth/refresh-token endpoint.
  // After the request, it clears the current user.
  async function logout() {
    try {
      const response = await api.post("/users/logout");
      if (response.status == 200) {
        setCurrentUser(null);
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
        console.log("Logged out user.");
      } else {
        console.log(
          `Failed to logout: server responded with status ${response.status}`
        );
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Failed to logout: ${error}`);
    }
  }

  // The provider component renders the AuthContext.Provider component with the current user, loading state, and login and logout functions as the value.
  // All children of this component will have access to these values.
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        currentUser,
        isLoading,
        logout,
        isAuthenticated,
        setCurrentUser,
        setIsAuthenticated,
        refreshToken,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

// This is a custom hook that provides an easy way to access the authentication context.
// It can be used in any functional component that is a child of the AuthProvider.
export function useAuth() {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);

  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useAuth must be used within an AuthProvider");
  }
  return {
    ...context,
  };
}
```

#### Test File

`frontend/src/components/NotAuthenticated/RegisterForm.test.tsx`

```
import { render, screen, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import RegisterForm from "./RegisterForm";
import { AuthProvider } from "../Context/AuthContext";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

describe("RegisterForm Component", () => {
  test("renders the form", () => {
    render(
      <AuthProvider>
        <Router>
          <RegisterForm />
        </Router>
      </AuthProvider>
    );

    expect(screen.getByText("Create a new account")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  test("fill register form and perform a successful registration", async () => {
    render(
      <AuthProvider>
        <Router>
          <RegisterForm />
        </Router>
      </AuthProvider>
    );

    // Simulate user typings
    await userEvent.type(screen.getByLabelText(/First Name/i), "Mr.");
    await userEvent.type(screen.getByLabelText(/Last Name/i), "Tester");

    await userEvent.type(
      screen.getByLabelText(/Email Address/i),
      "testregister@example.com"
    );

    await userEvent.type(
      screen.getAllByLabelText(/Password/i)[0],
      "password123"
    );
    await userEvent.type(
      screen.getByLabelText(/Verify Password/i),
      "password123"
    );

    // Simulate user clicking on Sign In button
    await userEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button", { name: "Sign Up" }));

    // Wait for the form to be submnitted and get the state to be updated
    await waitFor(() => screen.getByText("Registration Successful!"));

    // make sure the correct successful message is displayed
    expect(screen.getByText("Registration Successful!")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  test("fill register form with invalid email and get email not valid", async () => {
    render(
      <AuthProvider>
        <Router>
          <RegisterForm />
        </Router>
      </AuthProvider>
    );

    // Simulate user typings
    await userEvent.type(screen.getByLabelText(/First Name/i), "Mr.");
    await userEvent.type(screen.getByLabelText(/Last Name/i), "Tester");

    await userEvent.type(
      screen.getByLabelText(/Email Address/i),
      "example.com"
    );

    await userEvent.type(
      screen.getAllByLabelText(/Password/i)[0],
      "password123"
    );
    await userEvent.type(
      screen.getByLabelText(/Verify Password/i),
      "password123"
    );

    await waitFor(() => screen.getByText("Email is not valid!"));
    expect(screen.getByText("Email is not valid!"));
  });

  test("fill register form with invalid password and get password has to be more than 6 characters", async () => {
    render(
      <AuthProvider>
        <Router>
          <RegisterForm />
        </Router>
      </AuthProvider>
    );

    // Simulate user typings
    await userEvent.type(screen.getByLabelText(/First Name/i), "Mr.");
    await userEvent.type(screen.getByLabelText(/Last Name/i), "Tester");

    await userEvent.type(
      screen.getByLabelText(/Email Address/i),
      "errorpas6chars@example.com"
    );

    await userEvent.type(screen.getAllByLabelText(/Password/i)[0], "123");
    await userEvent.type(screen.getByLabelText(/Verify Password/i), "123");

    await waitFor(() =>
      screen.getByText("Password has to be at least 6 characters.")
    );
    expect(screen.getByText("Password has to be at least 6 characters."));
  });

  test("fill register form with passwords that don't match and get passwords do not match", async () => {
    render(
      <AuthProvider>
        <Router>
          <RegisterForm />
        </Router>
      </AuthProvider>
    );

    // Simulate user typings
    await userEvent.type(screen.getByLabelText(/First Name/i), "Mr.");
    await userEvent.type(screen.getByLabelText(/Last Name/i), "Tester");

    await userEvent.type(
      screen.getByLabelText(/Email Address/i),
      "errorpas6chars@example.com"
    );

    await userEvent.type(
      screen.getAllByLabelText(/Password/i)[0],
      "password123"
    );
    await userEvent.type(
      screen.getByLabelText(/Verify Password/i),
      "password1234"
    );

    await waitFor(() => screen.getAllByText("Passwords do not match"));
    expect(screen.getAllByText("Passwords do not match"));
  });
});
```

### My Request

I don't know how do I solve this problem, I am a new developer learning full stack for 6 months now, just got into testing 2 weeks ago. I generally understand the point of testing and how to do this, but doing it like this with mocking for my situation seems a little to complex. I don't even know if a test backend will help me, because this specific problem is because the test files or setup do not know how to handle 401 response codes.

This is happening to me like this, now because I have not considered using testing until recently, when my app was pretty much done, so I didn't think about adding tests until 2 weeks ago. And in any course that I've taken before, no one talked about testing, even though I was learning full-stack. So I basically learn testing as I go, but as you can see, it's not going to well.

Hope you can help me.

If you want to chat with me on Discord, I am W01v3n#6022

Thanks!